# Installing MeteorJS on Windows

Tags: meteor, installation

I've been trying to install Meteorjs on windows but error occurs. I already tried downloading another installer and restarting my computer but it doesn't work. It always pops 'failed to contact install server. Please try again' then displays the message 'One or more issues caused the setup to fail. Please fix the issues and then retry setup. For more information see the log file.'

Under that it displays '0x80070643. Fatal Error during installation.'

what to do with this?

Comment: Do you have a proxy or something interrupting your internet connection?

Comment: there is no proxy and i think nothing is interrupting the connection. I also tried connecting at our school internet and it still doesn't work. is the problem on my computer?

Comment: If it says `failed to contact install server.` it is not able to download the packages required to install the app from the meteor servers. Something is interrupting the connection proxy, firewall or antivirus. Maybe if you run it as 'admin' it may do better? or try switching the antivirus off

Answer (score 3):

One option is to run meteor preview for windows. Believe it is a standalone copy of meteor 1.1

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Preview-of-Meteor-on-Windows

(this doesn't address the issue of connecting to server though because when you try to create a meteor account you get a similar error).

there definitely is a way to install through command line on windows (which annoyingly I can't remember from my other machine). Perhaps through npm...

Comment: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Preview-of-Meteor-on-Windows/2e876f1bb8ffe83e38e82b92bca130bff7509d89

Answer (score 2):

Try to run the package as administrator.It works!

Comment: I have the exact same issue on windows xp, running it as administrator does nothing. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score -2):

Try this [guide](https://github.com/meteor/docs/blob/version-NEXT/long-form/alternate-windows-installation.md).

Download `.zip`, then unzip and set path environment variable.

Comment: This does not work. 7zip cannot extract the .meteor folder